# beforeEach on Mocha does not reset object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have the following in `state.js`:

```
var state = {};

function getState() {
  return state;
}

function setItem(key, value) {
  state[key] = value;
}

function resetState() {
  state = {};
}

exports.getState = getState;
exports.setItem = setItem;
exports.resetState = resetState;
```

In my Mocha test file, I have the following:

```
const { getState, setItem, resetState } = require("./state");
var assert = require("assert");

describe("...", function () {
    beforeEach(function() {
      resetState();
    })

    it("Case 1", function (done) {
      setItem("a", "b");
      assert.equal(JSON.stringify(getState()), JSON.stringify({"a": "b"}));
      done();
    });

    it("Case 2", function (done) {
      setItem("x", "y");
      assert.equal(JSON.stringify(getState()), JSON.stringify({"x": "y"}));
      done();
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, Case 2 fails because it looks like the `resetState()` function does not work here even though I'm calling it in `beforeEach`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me. Can't reproduce. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example